# How to find limit of a sequence $\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{1+a+a^2+...+a^n}{1+b+b^2+...+b^n}$?

Tags: limits

I have no idea how to solve this: $$\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{1+a+a^2+...+a^n}{1+b+b^2+...+b^n}$$ for: $|a|<1$, $|b|<1 $

I would be happy for any advice.

Thank you

Comment: Can you show what you have done so far?

Comment: You should play around with the series: $1+a+a^2 + \dots + a^n $. For starters plug in some numbers like a = 2,3 etc. and for n numbers like 2,3,4,5 etc. 
Maybe you will notice something :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The limit is $$\lim_{n\to \infty}\left(\frac{1+a+a^2+...+a^n}{1+b+b^2+...+b^n}\cdot\frac{1-a}{1-b}\cdot\frac{1-b}{1-a}\right)=\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{1-a^{n+1}}{1-b^{n+1}}\cdot\frac{1-b}{1-a}=\frac{1-b}{1-a}$$

**EDIT**

My thinking (pedagogic insert):
$1+a+a^2+...+a^n\;$ is the sum of first $n+1$ terms of geometric series.
The calculation that simplifies the sum and helps when looking for the limit, is multiplying by  $\frac{1-a}{1-a}.$
Similarly for $\;1+b+b^2+...+b^n.$
Both numerator and denominator converge (since  $|a|,|b|<1$).

Comment: I have 1 more questions. 1st: Can you please describe what was your way of thinking about this problem?
Maybe if you had some more ideas that didnt work, or did you just look at it and it was obvious?
Thanks

Comment: @LaurenSin Yes, I did just look, the method was in my memory. To my students I would say whote I completed in the solution.

Answer (score 6):

**Hint:** $1+x+x^2+\ldots + x^n = \frac{1-x^{n+1}}{1-x}$.